# Sum $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k^2}{2^k}$

Tags: summation

How to go about summing $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k^2}{2^k}$.

Comment: What have you tried towards solving this question?

Comment: Hint: Take two derivatives.

Comment: This will get you started: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/337942/16192

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439062/summation-of-series-sum-n-1-infty-fracnabn

Comment: Do you know any calculus? Are you familiar with $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\dots=2$?

Comment: Yes. I'm aware of the above relation.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. $x^2 f^{''}(x)$ gives me the summation that I need. But the index now starts from $2$. Any tip regarding that?

Comment: My bad! Got it, thanks! Answer will be $6$.

Comment: You're going to have to do summation by parts here.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1500335/sum-up-the-following-series-sumn-k-1-frack22k and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1072038/infinite-series-sum-k-1-infty-frack2k-and-sum-k-1-infty-frack and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2243801/how-to-determine-the-sum-of-an-infinite-series-that-is-neither-arithmetic-nor-ge and probably many more.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prove $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n^2}{2^n} = 6$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593996/how-to-prove-sum-n-0-infty-fracn22n-6)

Answer (score 2):

Since
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{2^n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{2^{n+1}}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{2^{n}}+1$$

implies that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{2^n}=2$$

we can use the same trick to see that

\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{2^n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(n+1)^2}{2^{n+1}}&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{2^{n}}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{2^{n}}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\\&=
\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{2^{n}}+3
\end{align}

therefore $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{2^{n}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{2^{n}}=6$$

Comment: Another way of doing this! Nice trick!

Answer (score 0):

Write $c^k$ as the forward difference of $c^k/(c-1)$ with $c=1/2.$ Find the sum from $1$ to $n$ of the given expression by using the summation by parts formula twice. Then take the limit as $n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: 1. What is a "Forward sum"? 2. Please can you use MathJax?

Comment: The forward difference operator on a function f(x) is defined by

Comment: The forward difference operator on a function f(x) is defined by Df(x)=f(x+1)-f(x). The summation by parts formula relates the sum of fDg(x) f rom 1 to n to the sum of  (D(f))g(x+1) and f(n+1)g(n+1) -f(1)g(1)I. The formula is analogous to integration by parts but there is shifting involved.

Answer (score 0):

Start with $\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k=\frac{1}{1-x}$ for $|x|\lt 1$

$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty kx^{k-1}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$

$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty k^2x^{k-1}=\frac{1+x}{(1-x)^3}$

Therefore $\sum_{k=0}^\infty k^2x^k=\frac{x(1+x)}{(1-x)^3}$

The question is the value of this last expression when $x=\frac{1}{2}$.  Ans $=6$.

Comment: I guess you've made a mistake.When taking the first derivative, the summation should start from $n=1$. Point is there is no $\frac1x$ term here. Also the summation is $6$.

Comment: My error (corrected} was in the third line derivative.  Starting the sum at 0 or 1 doesn't matter when there is a positive power of k as a coefficient, since that term is 0.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k=\frac{1}{1-x}, |x|<1.$$
Differentate w.r. $x$, then
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k x^k =\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}.$$
Differentiate again w.r. t. $x$, we get 
By putting $x=1/2$, we get $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k^2 x^k= \frac{x(1+x)}{(1-x)^3}.$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k^2}{2^k}=6$$

Comment: Your next to last line has a typo - should be $\sum k^2x^k$.

Comment: Oh! yes thanks.